# maven jboss build error

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have this setup for a project (not chosen by me, these are a given...)

jdk_1.6.0_32
jboss_eap 6.4.0
apache maven 3.0.4

I have a java enterprise application which I have to deploy on jboss.

I can build this application with no problem simply by giving the command

```
mvn -DskipTests clean install
```

But when I try to deploy this same app on a local jboss instance with the  command

```
mvn -DskipTests jboss-as:run
```

after some time I get this error in the build:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.5.Final:run (default-cli) on project bws-proto: Modules path 'null' is not a valid directory. -> [Help 1]

Do any of you have an idea why this happen and maybe suggest where to look?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you post your POM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check the path to jboss in "configuration" pom.xml, must be like this `youPath/jboss-eap-6.4/` **without** bin/

2) Check credentials for jboss (username and password)